# Creating Magento Mobile Theme for IPhone

Tags: iphone, magento

I am new to Magento and I would like to create the Mobile theme (IPhone) for my Magento Store.

Can any one give me simple introduction for Mobile Theme integration in Magento Store?

I have tried to implemented the mobile theme as per below reference Url :
http://smarttheme.cryozonic.com/installation
But Theme is not reflecting in Mobile Browser.

Any Help Much Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of introduction are you looking for? THis is very likely off topic on Stack Overflow, you should try Magento's support resources. However, consider doing a thorough search first, I wouldn't be surprised if there already were resources on this.

Comment: You can try to download Mobile themes from Magento connect(some of them are free, even developed by Magento Core team), it will help you to understand the topic better than any introduction article.

Comment: Take a look @ http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-mobilize-your-magento-site-for-iphone-android-mobile-commerce/

Comment: Hi all, I have tried to follow all the instruction as per the below Url http://smarttheme.cryozonic.com/installation. But i can only see the Magento desktop Theme in Mobile and IPhone. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: I am the author of the magento mobile theme that you mentioned at http://smarttheme.cryozonic.com/installation.

Just to avoid confusion, Magento comes with a stock mobile theme that you can configure, and then you have a number of developers writing commercial mobile themes with a different set of features, design and functionality. If you are wondering how to enable the default magento mobile theme you can follow the instructions at http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=51. The default theme has a different design from the one you mentioned, which you can try out here: http://smarttheme.cryozonic.com/demo